# PyQt6: How to transfer information between two windows?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I am making a project on PyQt6, and am stuck on something rather unsuspenseful. The major bit of my code formatting comes for the Qt Designer, and hence I couldn't get online solutions to work. The main window is as follows-

```
from settings1 import Ui_Settings, Comm


class Ui_Dialog(object):
### I open the 2nd window here, and set up a communication class ###
    def openWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Settings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.ui.set_fields(self.kernelSize, self.input2, self.input3, self.input4)
        self.comm = Comm()
        self.comm.submitted.connect(self.updateSettings)
        self.window.show()


### The function I'm supposed to receive the data into- ###

    # @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str,str,str,str,str)
    def updateSettings(self, kernel, i2, i3, i4, kvals):
        self.kernelSize = kernel
        self.input2 = i2
        self.input3 = i3
        self.input4 = i4
        self.kernel_vals = kvals
        self.kernel_ints = map(int, kvals.split(","))
        self.manKernel = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
        j = -1
        for i, item in enumerate(self.kernel_ints):
            if i % 3 == 0:
                j += 1
            self.manKernel[j][i] = item
```

File 2 (Settings1.py)

```
class Comm(QtCore.QObject):
    submitted = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str, str, str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Comm, self).__init__()

    def on_submit(self):
        self.submitted.emit(
            ui.lineEdit.text(),
            ui.lineEdit_2.text(),
            ui.lineEdit_3.text(),
            ui.lineEdit_4.text(),
            ui.lineEdit_5.text(),
        )

class Ui_Settings(object):

    def setupUi(self, Settings):

        Settings.setObjectName("Settings")
        Settings.resize(440, 235)

        self.saveSettings = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Settings)
        self.saveSettings.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 200, 93, 28))
        self.saveSettings.setObjectName("saveSettings")
        self.saveSettings.clicked.connect(Comm.on_submit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Settings = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    communicator = Comm()
    ui = Ui_Settings()
    ui.setupUi(Settings)
    Settings.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This returns me a `Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Birinder\Programs\Python\Edge AI\Project\settings1.py", line 22, in on_submit self.submitted.emit( AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'submitted'`

I've searched for solutions, but either they all use pyqt4/5, were answered 4+years ago, or use different systems altogether. I can't come with any workarounds. I've  tried moving the submitted signal inside the main class, in its own class, outside all classes, but nothing came to fruitition.

Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Most of the solutions you found are probably still valid, the issue is in your code: `Comm` is a class, calling `Comm.on_submit` behaves like a static method, so `self` becomes the argument of the `clicked` signal (which is a bool). A theoretical solution would be to change it to `self.saveSettings.clicked.connect(communicator.on_submit)`, but that wouldn't completely solve all the other problems you're having, starting from the fact that you're directly using (and modifying) pyuic classes, which is always discouraged as it always results in issues like yours.

Comment: Start by creating a new script as your main one, regenerate those UI classes with pyuic and follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to implement your logic. Then, remember that you should generally avoid to access global references, as you did with `ui` (or even as "theoretically suggested" by me with `communicator`).

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you may need to send `communicator` instance `ui = Ui_Settings(communicator)` and keep it as `self.communicator = communicator` and later use `self.communicator.on_submit`.